# Rellenar un Select de Laravel, con un evento Change de otro Select

Tags: laravel

¿Cómo puedo mediante el evento change de un `Form::select` llenar otro `Form::select`?

Ejemplo:

Cargo un Select principal con algunos departamentos:

**Controller**

```
$masterareas = dk_master_area::orderBy('name','asc')->get();
$data = array();
   foreach ($masterareas as $masterarea) {
      $areas = dk_area::where('id_master_area','=',$masterarea->id)->orderBy('name','asc')->get();
      $tdata = array();
      foreach ($areas as $area) {
          $tdata[$area->id] = $area->name;
      }
      $data[$masterarea->name] = $tdata;
    }
return view('user/create', ['areas'=>$data]);
```

**View:**

```
{!!Form::select('areas',$areas,null,['id'=>'areas','class'=>'form-control'])!!}
```

*Este es el resultado:*

[image: Es es el resultado]

Dependiendo de el área que escoja, debo buscar el departamento de esa área para cargar los cargos disponibles para el Departamento, los cuales a nivel de base ya están relacionados, de manera que puedo saber que cargo pertenece a tal departamento.

Pero no se como puedo hacer, para que al elegir un area, puedo cargar en un segundo select, los cargos. ¿Debo utilizar el mismo `Form::select` o sencillamente un select normal? No quiero tener problemas a la hora de intentar guardar los datos.

Comment: Hola @Maykol Rivas tiene que ser directamente con PHP(laravel)? te podria ayudar con un codigo js que te puede servir

Comment: @Daniel Cualquier ayuda que me permita resolver mi duda y no tener conflictos a la hora de guardar, Es bienvenida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no se bien si estas utilizando ese `select` dentro de un formulario *(pues dices que después de que no haya conflictos al guardar no hay problema)* o no, pero independientemente de eso has esto:

```js
$.(document).ready(function($) {

      $.ajax({
          url: 'listar_areas', //ruta donde tengas la funcion listar areas
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(respuesta) {
            var response = respuesta;

            for (var i = response.length; i >= 0; i--) {
              $('#area_de_trabajo').append('<option value="' + response[i].id_area + '">' + response[i].area_descripcion + '</option>';
              }
            })
          .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
          })

          $('#area_de_trabajo').change(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'listar_cargos', //ruta donde enviaras el id del area para listar luego los cargos
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                  'id_area': $(this).val();
                })
              .done(function(respuesta) {
                  var response = respuesta;

                  for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    $('#cargo').append('<option value="' + response[i].id_cargo + '">' + response[i].cargo_descripcion + '</option>';
                    }
                  })
                .fail(function() {
                  console.log("error");
                })
              });
          });
```

```html
<select name="area_de_trabajo" id="area_de_trabajo">
    </select>

<select name="cargo" id="cargo">
    </select>
```

Comment: Si, efectivamente uso un formulario con el  `{!!Form::open()!!}` y dentro de el tengo el campo, no me afecta tener los campos con `Form::text` y otros dibujados con html, normalmente?

Comment: no no importa, tengas tus selects dentro de un formulario o no siempre el JS va a correr y se te van a listar, pero claramente esta que si tu vas a usar esos id de los selects para luego guardarlos en tu base de datos a un usuario por ejemplo ps obviamente tendrias que meter los selects dentro del form.

Comment: Cambiando una par de cosas, pude dar con una solución.